# Advice on buying a server for virtualization

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012-r2, dell-poweredge

So I am a student. I'm looking to buy a server for virtualization. I would like to test different product and make testing environments (like in production) to expand my knowedgle with server administration and networking. On the host I would run Windows Server 2012 R2.

I was looking to buy a refurbished Dell PowerEdge M610 Blade Server.

Specifications:

-2x 2.40 GHz Quad-core Xeon E5530
-48GB (12x4GB) DDR3 ECC Reg -1333Mhz RAM
-1x HP 146GB 2.5" SFF 10K SAS disk
-1x Samsung SSD 250 Pro 256GB (purchased separately)
-PERC H700 Modular with 512MB battery-backed cache
-Two embedded Broadcom® NetXtreme II™ 5709 Gigabit Ethernet NIC

I have also an option to change from the Quad-core Xeon E5530 to a Hex-core Xeon X5650.

Because I'm new in this field and I don't have experience I would need some advice.

Is it enough to run 15 virtual machines?
Is it a good choice for my purpose?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Welcome.  Questions about shopping recommendations are specifically considered outside the scope of the site, as are questions that will encourage opinion-based answers, so your question is likely to get closed.  Reword it to just focus on the technical questions you need answered.  Can a computer with XYZ specs handle 15 virtual machines?  Would quad core vs hex core have a substantive effect on performance?

Comment: Particularly because you are a student, I would recommend looking into cloud services.  This will likely be a much cheaper option for you, since you're only paying for what you're using and you can shut it down when you're done.  Also, you can run your VMs on your own laptop (should you get enough RAM).  This is ideal for testing, and you don't have to spend a lot of money to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Should be more than enough to run 15 virtual machines, though, you did not specify what these virtual machines are going to be running to it is difficult to give you a hard yes/no answer.

Also keep in mind, a blade server requires a blade chassis.